# React useEffect hooks return () => cleanup() vs return cleanup

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, codemirror

I have a question about `useEffect`'s cleanup callback function. In one word, `return cleanup` gives an error, but `return () => cleanup()` works well. Yes, they are different, but how are they different? Does anyone know how to explain? Thanks,

I came across this question while I am writing with codemirror.

The error message I see is

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'plugins')
```

My hooks

```js
export const useCodeMirror = () => {
  const state = ...
  const parent = ...
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const view = new EditorView({state: state, parent: parent})
    // return view.destroy raises an error
    return () => view.destroy()  // works perfectly
  }, [element])
}
```

node_modules/@codemirror/view/dist/index.js L:6740-6750

```
    destroy() {
        for (let plugin of this.plugins)
            plugin.destroy(this);
        this.plugins = [];
        this.inputState.destroy();
        this.dom.remove();
        this.observer.destroy();
        if (this.measureScheduled > -1)
            cancelAnimationFrame(this.measureScheduled);
        this.destroyed = true;
    }
```

package.json

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "codemirror": "^6.0.1",
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: `gives an error that says view is undefined` Are you sure that's what the error says? I could see it saying that `this` is undefined...

Comment: @NicholasTower Hi. Thanks for the comment. I updated my question to show code that throws an error and exact error statement. Yes, `this` is used. I'm still not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's normally fine to return a cleanup function directly, rather than wrapping it in an additional arrow function. The only reason the additional function is needed in this case because `destroy` uses `this`.

For regular functions, the value of `this` is determined by how the function is called. So if you have code that says `view.destroy()`, then the characters `view.` are the reason that `this` gets set to `view`. That's why `() => view.destroy()` one works: you are explicitly saying what `this` should be, as you call the function.

But if you just return `view.destroy`, you are not calling the function, just returning a reference of it to react. React doesn't know anything about `view`, it just knows you returned a function. So when react later calls your function, it doesn't know what to set `this` to, and so `this` gets set to undefined. Since it's undefined, `this.plugins` causes the error you see.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer. For someone who wants to learn more, this mdn tutorial would help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#binding_this_with_prototype_and_static_methods